# Add button to open URL in ArcMap 10

Tags: arcmap, vba

I want to be able to add a button into ArcGIS for my users, something like this:

http://gis.utah.gov/code-visual-basic/vba-link-from-arcmap-to-google-maps

Only, using VBA in ArcMap 10 now seems to be an issue, I can't find the UI control option anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you installed the VBA license for v10?

Comment: Check this Python Add-In Script (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/streetview-bing-birds-eye-add-in/92839#92839)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS 10, [VBA is not recommended](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/supportcenter/archive/2010/06/25/farewell-to-vba.aspx), you should use Add-Ins instead: [Add-Ins](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/)

Comment: VBA is not retired yet as Simon Jackson has commented.

Comment: @artwork21, Changed the text a bit to reflect that, but the message is clear from ESRI, VBA will be removed and the you should use 10 release to migrate a way form VBA code and not write new VBA code.

Comment: Thanks, bit annoying but never mind.

Comment: @gisuser, Just for the record you can still use VBA at 10, so if you wanted to achieve this you just need to obtain the free VBA license from Esri.  But yes - think about moving to add-ins/Python/ArcGIS Run-Time

Answer (score 1):

Check out this thread:
[Creating StreetView/Bing Bird's Eye Add-In?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/streetview-bing-birds-eye-add-in)

There's an inadvertent space in the google url, but I was able to build the add-in just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate **HTML Popups** for layers.

For more info see http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/00s5/00s50000002r000000.htm