# ArcMap 10 How to create a tool to use with a Vb.Net script?

Tags: arcmap, vb.net, vba

I have a VB.net scrip that I would like to run from the toolbar.  In VBA, you would create a buttton that would collect the xy coordinates and pass the variables to the script for running.  I can't seem to figure out how to pass the variables.  When i create a button and click, the script ask for the variables before I have time to click the map.

Here is an example of the script I am using:

[Creating StreetView/Bing Bird's Eye Add-In?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/streetview-bing-birds-eye-add-in)

Thanks a bunch!

Heather

Comment: VB.NET *script*? I don't think such a thing exists. Are you sure you are talking about VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a [UIToolControl](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/ComponentHelp/esriCore/IUIToolControlEvents.htm) not a UIButtonControl.  UIToolControls events interact with the view.

[Creating custom commands with VBA and UI Controls](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_custom_commands_with_VBA_and_UI_Controls)

Answer (score 0):

For walk-thru of how to build a button using the "Add-in" technique see [ESRI's example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/), which is mentioned as a resource in answering [a previous question on this site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/first-attempt-using-arcobjects-esris-add-ins-example-unclear/17863#17863) that may be of use to you.

Comment: I believe Heather is attempting to add the script to a VBA toolbar, not an add-in.